# Firefox doesn't remember username, but remembers password

Tags: html, firefox, browser, autocomplete

I use few websites on which i would like to remember username and password.
Login mechanism is divided on two steps, in first user gives username and in next step password. Firefox remembers both of them but in next login try, username is not filled so I must fill it manually. It doesn't propose any values even if I start typing. Its not my website so I can't modify code to the working state. There is possibility that owner made it as intended but I don't care. I want to have autofill both fields, not only password field. It's my credentials, not owner of website. I have found some javascript code running as a bookmark
`javascript:(function(){var fm=document.getElementsByTagName('form');for(i=0;i<fm.length;i++){fm[i].setAttribute('autocomplete','on');}})()`

and it even worked for some time on one of these problematic websites (autofill proposed me a value after typed first letter) but now it doesn't work any longer.
The problematic website i want to have fully working autofill is

`h**ps://www.orange.pl/twojekonto/zaloguj`

Is there anything I can do to force it? Maybe other javascript inject by bookmark? I am using Firefox 91.0.2.